# How to keep the function key locked on Lenovo E431?

Tags: keyboard, lenovo-laptop

For the Lenovo e431, how do you keep the function key locked?

Right now pressing F1-F12 activates the multimedia controls by default.  To get to the standard F1-F12, you have to hold down Fn+the function key. This used to be adjustable in the BIOS, but for this laptop model, it no longer is available.

You can press Fn+esc, and it locks it for that session, but when the computer reboots, this is reset back to the default.

Is there a way so that the default is not the multimedia function keys, but just the standard, legacy function keys?

Comment: Do you have the keyboard drivers installed? Apparently you can change some settings in the control panel http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Edge-S-series/Disable-Fn-Keys-E420/td-p/803609

Comment: Thank you for the response, but the E series (E431) does not have that particular setting in the keyboard control panel setting.  I tried looking for specific updated drivers for this keyboard, but none were found.

Answer (score 58):

'Fn + Esc' Should lock it, [but you'll need bios version 1.25+ to keep this config after reboot, since it had an issue fixed on 1.25:](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles/heuj15ww.txt)

> <1.25>
>   - (New) Modified Power off USB timing.
>   - (New) Added New Panel Support.
>   - (Fix) Fixed an issue related to post hang up issue with special input KB/Mouse on docking
>   - (Fix) Fixed an issue related to unsupported resolution appeared during VGA/HDMI first plug in.
>   **- (Fix) Fixed an issue that Fn lock can't be kept after reboot.**

You can download it (and anything related to ThinkPad Edge E431) here:
[ThinkPad Edge E431 Download Page en-us](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-edge-laptops/thinkpad-edge-e431)

Btw you can also switch Fn and Left Ctrl on BIOS :)

Comment: It's not, check the version history on the first link I provided. I edited the aswer to reflect it... Yeah I should've picked other name to avoid this confusion, but I stand by it XD

Comment: This also works on a Lenovo T440

Answer (score 11):

I have a Lenovo Ideapad, model 80XM.

I was able to change this setting by going into the Lenovo settings app called "Lenovo Vantage" that came installed with my model.

Go into the app, click "Hardware Settings" > "More" > "Function Keys" > then select "F1-F12" instead of "Hot Keys".

---

**Edit:**

My app has been updated and changed, now you go to:

- Lenovo Vantage App
- Hardware Settings
- Input
- Click on F1-F12 to use those settings instead

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Just in case someone encounters this issue: For some reason Fn sticky keys was enabled in my case, which caused fn+lock not to work properly, thus Lenovo Vantage didn't even allow changing the setting until I turned that off. It's right under it in the advanced settings or something.

Comment: I installed the "Lenovo Vantage" app through the Microsoft store, via Chrome. The menu is different now, it's "Device" > "My Device Settings" > "Input & Accessories" under a header titled (somewhat ironically) "Intelligent Keyboard". Thanks for the tip on the Lenovo Vantage app, you helped me fix a very aggravating issue.

Answer (score 10):

I was searching like a man possessed to find how to return to F1-12 legacy mode (Lenovo Ideapad 110) because the FN hot keys were driving me nuts, especially while gaming.
I FINALLY found one post where the suggestion worked, after having tried 1000 different things from different posts:

- While holding shift restart your PC and continue holding shift until a menu pops up.
- Select Troubleshoot
- Advanced Options
- UEFI Firmware Settings
- Restart.
  You will now boot into BIOS.
- Then go to Configuration
- Hotkey Mode and disable.
- Save your settings,
- boot to your OS and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

My IT guy found it: you have to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> simultaneously, this will turn Function lock on or off and thus enable the function keys with or without the <kbd>Fn</kbd>-key.

Comment: OP stated that in the question. ("*You can press Fn+esc, and it locks it for that session*") The question was hot to turn it on permanently.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have this specific model (I have the W540), I have an option to make it permanent in the BIOS

http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Edge-S-series/Keeping-quot-Fn-quot-key-on/td-p/449937

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold and the Fn key for about 20 to 30 seconds. There would be a menu that pops up that asks whether you want to switch back to legacy mode. Just select the legacy option and you would be back to the old keyboard F1-F12 function that you always wanted.