# How to make PrtSc and Insert keys on Lenovo act normal?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, lenovo-laptop, hotkeys

My Lenovo ThinkBook 13s-IML shares its <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> and <kbd>Insert</kbd> keys with phone keys, which trigger a "Skype for Business 2016" overlay when pressed (despite that not even being installed). I've followed [these](https://superuser.com/questions/616156/how-to-keep-the-function-key-locked-on-lenovo-e431/1294056) [steps](https://superuser.com/questions/1221447/make-function-keys-behave-as-normal-on-a-lenovo-laptop) to try and F-lock those keys, but that only worked for <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd>, despite <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> and <kbd>Insert</kbd> acting normal while holding <kbd>Fn</kbd>.

Is there a way to not have to hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> to use <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> and <kbd>Insert</kbd>?

Comment: It sounds like the keys were mapped to open Skype. You could use a program like [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to remap them to perform the action you want. EDIT: [Example here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Intro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As suggested](https://superuser.com/questions/1629193/how-to-make-prtsc-and-insert-keys-on-lenovo-act-normal?noredirect=1#comment2487977_1629193), I tried AutoHotkey. `fix_printscreen.ahk` works:

```
#+O::PrintScreen
```

But the annoying overlay still appears.

[image: AutoHotkey]

Searching the Registry for "Skype for Business 2016" returns a bunch of Office 2016 keys such as `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Registration\{BDB32189-C636-46CD-A011-FFB834B552D9}` (also strange because I've uninstalled MS Office), leading me to find this service (with German description): `"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun\OfficeClickToRun.exe" /service`, but stopping and disabling that didn't stop the overlay. I've modified the values, but even after a reboot the overlay text didn't change.

Via [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) I found **the cause**: `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\E0469640.LenovoUtility_3.2.1.0_x64__5grkq8ppsgwt4\VFS\ProgramFilesX64\Lenovo\LenovoUtility\utility.exe`, launched by `C:\Users\Cees\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\lenovoutility.exe` aka `LenovoUtilityUWP` in Task Manager's Startup tab:
[image: Startup apps]
Disabling that *and* ending its task worked:
[image: Running apps]